# One row result with multiple join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, left-join, rows

I have 3 tables like the following.

Table "mansioni":

```
id_mansione | desc_mansione
    1       |   production
    2       |   office
    3       |   transport
```

Table "dipendente": store id, name and surname:

```
id_dip | nome_dip | cognome_dip
 1     |  piero   | rossi
 2     |  marco   | rossi
```

Table dipendenti_iddip: store the association between "dipendente" and table "mansioni"

```
iddip_mansione |  num_mansione | id_mansione
       1       |        1      |     1
       1       |        2      |     2
       2       |        1      |     2
       2       |        2      |     3
```

Now I need a query that give me a result like this:

```
id_dip |  nome_dip |  cognome_dip | mansione1 | mansione2 | mansione3
   1   |   piero   |    rossi     | production| office    | 
   2   |   marco   |    rossi     | office    | transport |
```

I arrived to the following query but with this I can only see the "id_mansione" and not the "desc mansione" field

```
select i.id_dip,
       i.nome_dip,
       i.cognome_dip,
       max(case when t.num_mansione='1' then t.id_mansione end) Mansione1,
       max(case when t.num_mansione='2' then t.id_mansione end) Mansione2,
       max(case when t.num_mansione='3' then t.id_mansione end) Mansione3
from dipendente i
left join dipendenti_iddip t
  on i.id_dip = t.iddip_mansione
group by i.id_dip, i.nome_dip, i.cognome_dip
```

How can I arrive to my result?
Thanks...

Comment: Add another `JOIN` to table that contains the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add join on `mansioni` and replace `t.id_mansione` with `m.desc_mansione`

```
select i.id_dip,
       i.nome_dip,
       i.cognome_dip,
       max(case when t.num_mansione = '1' then m.desc_mansione end) Mansione1,
       max(case when t.num_mansione = '2' then m.desc_mansione end) Mansione2,
       max(case when t.num_mansione = '3' then m.desc_mansione end) Mansione3
from dipendente i
       join dipendenti_iddip t
            on i.id_dip = t.iddip_mansione
       join mansioni m on m.id_mansione = t.id_mansione
group by i.id_dip
```